# How install and run vue js application on Centos 7

Tags: vue.js, installation

I want to install vuejs and run it on Centos 7, I want to run it inside a specific folder.

Comment: Why not use docker with npm and setup vue-cli3

Answer (score 2):

[updated]

It's a little bit different, but works fine to me on CentOS 7
(deprecated but working fine)

$ curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -

$ sudo yum install -y nodejs

$ node --version

$ npm --version

$ sudo npm install -g @vue/cli

$ vue create [projectname]

go to the folder of project name:

$ cd projectname

$ npm run serve

open your internet browser and type http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Node and NPM first. On CentOS 7 you can do this by running the following commands.

```sh
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -
```

```sh
sudo yum install nodejs
```

After this, confirm that Node and NPM are installed by running `node --version` and `npm --version`.

Then you need to install `vue-cli`. This makes creating Vue applications very easy. Install it by running `npm install -g @vue/cli`. After that has installed, you can create new projects by running `vue create <project-name>`. Once you have created the project, you can run it locally using `npm run serve`.